# Failed to load unity-gtk-module

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3

I have some issues with unity GTK on CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) with Gnome 3.

```
$ emacs
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

$ evince
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

I tried installing gtk2-engines packages but it did not fix it.

```
$ sudo yum install gtk2-engines*
Package gtk2-engines-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gtk2-engines-devel-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

and reinstalling them:

```
$ sudo yum reinstall gtk2-engines*                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[sudo] password for klaus: 
[...]
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gtk2-engines.x86_64 0:2.20.2-7.el7 will be reinstalled
---> Package gtk2-engines-devel.x86_64 0:2.20.2-7.el7 will be reinstalled
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies
======================================================================
Package         Arch          Version       Repository    Size
======================================================================
Reinstalling:
 gtk2-engines       x86_64    2.20.2-7.el7  epel          301 k
 gtk2-engines-devel x86_64    2.20.2-7.el7  epel          17 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================
Reinstall  2 Packages

Total download size: 318 k
Installed size: 1.2 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/2): gtk2-engines-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64.rpm       | 301 kB  00:00:00     
(2/2): gtk2-engines-devel-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64.rpm |  17 kB  00:00:00     
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                    2.7 MB/s | 318 kB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : gtk2-engines-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64         1/2 
  Installing : gtk2-engines-devel-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64   2/2 
  Verifying  : gtk2-engines-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64         1/2 
  Verifying  : gtk2-engines-devel-2.20.2-7.el7.x86_64   2/2 

Installed:
  gtk2-engines.x86_64 0:2.20.2-7.el7 
  gtk2-engines-devel.x86_64 0:2.20.2-7.el7                                                                                                 

Complete!
```

... but I still have the error

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the packages? `yum reinstall gtk2-engines*`

Comment: I have just done it but I am still having this error :(

Comment: The `appmenu` plugin for Xfce moves Gtk apps' menu bar to a global menu bar, and it uses this option, which came from the Unity desktop's global menu bar. I have the same problem, which I am currently investigating. I added this option in a few places on an experimental box, but by mistake, I used the old Unity syntax, not the new Appmenu syntax. Now I need to find what to change, where...